# Как объединить две формы заявки?

Tags: php, html, form

Есть форма для подтверждения номера по смс (апи с смс-центром):

```
    <form method="post" action="act.php" target="ifr">
<div class="form-label">
<table>
<tr><td>Номер телефона<td><input name="phone" type="tel" id="phone">
    <span id="valid-msg" class="hide">✓</span>
    <span id="error-msg" class="hide"></span>
    <input type="submit" name="sendsms" value="Выслать код">
<tr><td><br/>
<tr><td>Код подтверждения<td><input name="code" size="6">&nbsp;
<tr><td><br/>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="ok" value="Подтвердить"><td colspan="2" id="_out">
</table>
</div>
</form>
<iframe name="ifr" frameborder="0" height="0" width="0" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
```

сам act.php:

```
include_once "smsc_api.php";

if (isset($_POST["sendsms"])) {
    $r = send_sms($_POST["phone"], ok_code($_POST["phone"]));

    if ($r[1] > 0)
        echo "Код подтверждения отправлен на номер ".$_POST["phone"];
}

if (isset($_POST["ok"])) {
    $oc = ok_code($_POST["phone"]);

    if ($oc == $_POST["code"])
        echo "Номер подтвержден!";
    else
        echo $htmlmy;
}

echo "'</script>";

function ok_code($s) {
    return hexdec(substr(md5($s."<секретная строка>"), 7, 5));
}
?>
```

А есть форма заявки обычная, где нужно заполнить имя-мейл и отправить форму. Получаем данные из формы себе на мейл, и ссылку отправившему:

```
                <form action="send.php" method="post" onsubmit="yaCounter51979766.reachGoal('send'); return true;" class="c_form c_form-bottom pb-5" id="form">
                    <p class="mb-3">Заполните форму и получите книгу <br>«Цифровое золото»</p>
                    <div class="form-label">
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-label">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="tags" value="">
                    <button type="submit" name="email"  class="button ml-0 ml-sm-3 mt-3 mt-sm-0">СКАЧАТЬ КНИГУ</button>
                </form>


<div class="popup popup-thy popup">
    <div class="popup-close">x</div>
    <div class="popup-title">Спасибо за заявку!</div>
    <div class="popup_body">
        <p>Ближайшее время Вам на почту придет ссылка на скачивание книги!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Знатоки, подскажите, как вставить это подтверждение телефона в форму?

Comment: А по какому принципу вы их объединить хотите? Что в итоге должно получиться,

Comment: @doox911 я хочу, чтобы только с подтвержденным номером можно было отправить всю форму. Т.е. на свой мейл я получаю данные (подтвержденный телефон, мейл, имя).

Comment: Подскажу логику. Вам надо использовать `ajax`.При завершении ввода (например) телефонного номера срабатывает событие, которое вызывает первый фай. Он отдаёт `json` в ответе. Далее скрипт анализирует ответ и активирует кнопку **Скачать книгу**.  И на странице не должно быть 2 тега `form`.